# How to Kill Hive Query, without knowing application id?

Tags: hadoop, hive

My hive-server2 list a few running jobs, so I can find the various query_id.

But there is not yarn-application information in the Yarn 8088 pages.

My question is how to kill the running job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yarn as resource manager, you can find all running jobs by running the following in shell:

```
yarn application -list -appStates ALL
```

You can change ALL to RUNNING etc. depending on what application state you are interested in seeing.

An alternative command to the above to see running applications is:

```
mapred job -list
```

In order to kill a specific application/job, with YARN you can run:

```
yarn application -kill <application_id>
```

Or otherwise:

```
mapred job -kill <job_id>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my yarn application list is empty, so this way can not work..

Comment: What are you using as Resource/Application manager for your setup?

Comment: We use Cloudera platform,  most of  hive queries is submitted by HUE;  However, we built a tool to quick look a tables sample by thrift , "Select * From [tablename] Limit 100 "; the code is submitted by hive-server-thrift ;  I can find this queryId in our Hive Server2 , but it doesnot  generate a Yarn job-id.